# Control over Listbox not prevent scrolling

Tags: c#, listbox, windows-phone-8, overlap

I made a hiding bar into my application using a simple control, using a TranslateTransform.
When the bar is showed is overlapping a listbox.
What i didn't expect is that scrolling on the control don't prevent to scroll also the overlapped listbox.
I need that the listbox don't scroll when i'm working on the control.

I made a video in order to better explain the issue.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9UM2lzPz8p0

[Update]

solved using UseOptimizedManipulationRouting="False"

Comment: You write your title `windows phone 8` but tagged with `windows phone 7`?

Comment: I had no reputation to tag wp8.

Comment: There is no reputation need for tagging. Anyway, updated your question.